# HTML5 Keyboard audio with old IE fallback. IE8 image issue

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-8, gif, imagemap

[image: broken ie8 gif or png]

The code below works great in all modern browsers.  I'm using a transparent gif as an image map so I can swap different keyboard images/divs below it to make the keyboard appear to be playable.  In IE8 everything functions, but I get that ugly icon in the top left corner.  Any ideas?

`<div id="pressed-keys" class="kb-none">
            <div id="kb-audio"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="mapped-keys" class="hide">
            <img src="keyboard-overlay.gif" border="0" width="316" height="250" usemap="#keyboard-map" border="0" alt="Keyboard" class="alpha-0" style="background:transparent;border:0;" />
            <map name="keyboard-map" id="keyboard-map">
                <area id="key-1" class="kb1-C2" shape="poly" coords="77,155,88,149,157,189,165,182,213,208,193,229" href="#" alt="C">
                <area id="key-2" class="kb2-C2s" shape="poly" coords="97,138,89,142,89,149,157,188,167,180,155,167" href="#" alt="C#">
                <area id="key-3" class="kb3-D2" shape="poly" coords="111,138,105,141,155,166,168,179,166,182,214,208,232,191,184,168,182,170" href="#" alt="D">
                <area id="key-4" class="kb4-D2s" shape="poly" coords="113,131,113,137,181,168,191,163,179,151,120,127" href="#" alt="D#">
                <area id="key-5" class="kb5-E2" shape="poly" coords="233,190,186,168,192,163,180,150,129,129,131,129,247,174" href="#" alt="E">
                <area id="key-6" class="kb6-F2" shape="poly" coords="248,173,259,161,215,145,209,149,140,125,133,129" href="#" alt="F">
                <area id="key-7" class="kb7-F2s" shape="poly" coords="140,125,141,117,146,115,205,134,215,144,208,149" href="#" alt="F#">
                <area id="key-8" class="kb8-G2" shape="poly" coords="260,160,270,149,226,135,224,137,205,133,216,144" href="#" alt="G">
                <area id="key-9" class="kb9-G2s" shape="poly" coords="223,136,155,116,156,110,160,107,219,124,228,133" href="#" alt="G#">
                <area id="key-10" class="kb10-A2" shape="poly" coords="221,124,229,133,228,135,270,149,278,139,237,127,236,127" href="#" alt="A">
                <area id="key-11" class="kb11-A2s" shape="poly" coords="169,108,170,103,174,101,231,115,239,123,236,127" href="#" alt="A#">
                <area id="key-12" class="kb12-B2" shape="poly" coords="278,138,286,129,234,117,240,123,238,126" href="#" alt="B">
                <area id="key-13" class="kb13-C3" shape="poly" coords="285,128,233,115,230,114,182,102,185,100,250,114,253,111,291,120" href="#" alt="C">
                <area id="key-14" class="kb14-C3s" shape="poly" coords="249,113,186,99,186,94,189,92,245,103,252,110" href="#" alt="C#">
                <area id="key-15" class="kb15-D3" shape="poly" coords="291,119,296,113,260,105,257,106,247,104,253,110" href="#" alt="D">
                <area id="key-16" class="kb16-D3s" shape="poly" coords="257,105,244,102,196,92,196,89,201,86,253,95,261,102" href="#" alt="D#">
                <area id="key-17" class="kb17-E3" shape="poly" coords="296,111,301,106,256,97,262,102,260,104" href="#" alt="E">
            </map>
        </div>`

Comment: FYI, When I remove the image map entirely the IE image icon disappears.    Image maps seem to be the only viable solution since we don't want to use Flash and we need clickable polygons.

Comment: It looks like IE8 doesn't like the id and class tags I added to the <area> tags for jQuery.